# How to make self.request.user return the user attached to token?

Tags: django, api, authentication, django-rest-framework, token

I am using token authentication in Django Rest Framework, and am passing a token into the header of my request. This token is attached to a user. How would I make it so that when 'self.request.user' is called, the user attached to the token in the request is returned?

Failing this, more specifically I need some sort of way to change the following 'perform_create()' function in my view to instead set 'author' to the user attached to the token.

perform_create() function currently:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(author = self.request.user)
```

I need it so 'author' is set to the user attached to the token in the header.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT: I am unable to use session based authentication in this implementation**

Comment: If your authentication is working correctly then `self.request.user` should already be the logged in user.

Comment: I am unable to use session authentication in this application so my understanding is this would not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the exact same code (with type checking at runtime) to get the user model in a token authentication system and can confirm that it works.

```py
def perform_create(self, serializer: ModelSerializer) -> None:
    serializer.save(registrant=self.request.user)
```

`registrant` is the Foreign Key to the user model:

```py
# models.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Model(models.Model):
    # ...
    registrant = models.ForeignKey(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    # ...
```

**EDIT:** This is further confirmed in the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication):

> If successfully authenticated, `TokenAuthentication` provides the following credentials.
>
> - `request.user` will be a Django User instance.
> - `request.auth` will be a `rest_framework.authtoken.models.Token` instance.

Comment: Would this not require session based authentication? What sets request.user equal to the user attached to the token?

Comment: I modified my answer by citing the documentation to prove to you it does not require session authentication.

Comment: 'What sets request.user equal to the user attached to the token' The `TokenAuthentication` class. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#how-authentication-is-determined

Comment: Check out the [source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authentication.py#L195) for the `TokenAuthentication` class. It returns the user model based on the token during authentication.